# Using Trigger to update table in another database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

im using the following trigger to update the user table in another database in mysql 5.0.7
The creation of trigger gives no error but upon updating the user table in the first database the trigger is not working. Any suggestions?

```
DELIMITER $$         
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_update_user;

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_user;

AFTER UPDATE ON db_test.user  FOR EACH ROW;
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE db_testplus.user;
    SET  name = NEW.name;

    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I also used this code without the semicolons but still the same

```
DELIMITER $$         
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_update_user

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_user

AFTER UPDATE ON db_test.user  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE db_testplus.user
    SET  name = NEW.name

    WHERE id = NEW.id
END;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Finally the code that worked

```
delimiter |
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_update_user|
 CREATE TRIGGER after_update_user AFTER UPDATE ON db_test.user
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE db_testplus.user SET name = NEW.name WHERE id = NEW.id;
  END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: The table in the second database is not updating after update in the first table

Comment: What's with the semicolons all over the place?

Comment: In one post there was this suggestion to put semicolons after every statement so I tried with this

Answer (score 2):

Could you please check below

```
AFTER UPDATE ON db_test.user  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE db_testplus.user
    SET  name = NEW.name

    WHERE id = NEW.id
END;
```

Comment: did you used `;` after `END` or after `WHERE id = NEW.id`.. I am asking as your update says you are using after `WHERE id = NEW.id`... Try with adding `;` after END as I have shown...

Comment: Does it matter what Storage Engine is being used. Im using MyISAM

Comment: not sure, let me check on google... I am not much in MYSQL but I share that much I know...

Comment: check if below link helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507636/oracle-problem-creating-trigger-that-updates-another-table,  http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/use-trigger-to-update-data-in-another-db-149985.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799933/update-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-a-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765258/how-to-use-a-trigger-to-update-a-column-in-one-table-from-an-insert-on-another-t

Comment: more links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765258/how-to-use-a-trigger-to-update-a-column-in-one-table-from-an-insert-on-another-t

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the problem it was about using delimiters after DROP statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_user

AFTER UPDATE ON db_test.user  FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE TABLE db_testplus.user
  SET  name = NEW.name
  WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

Omitting begin-end keywords worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in MySQL 5.1.73:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update`
AFTER UPDATE ON `test_table`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE another_db.updated_table
SET  some_name = NEW.some_name
WHERE id = NEW.id
```