# Updating a value in another database table each time a value is changed in another database table

Tags: mysql

hi2,

Could anyone please show me how to update a *dataValue* each time a data in another database changes its value ?

Here is a screenshot of my 2 databases
I would like that; 

Each time a **value** in **database1-table1** is changing,

It sends a trigger to change the **age** value in **database2-useragetable**

[image]

I attempt to create a trigger from this link.
[Using Trigger to update table in another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910617/using-trigger-to-update-table-in-another-database)

And Here is the code and the screenshot of it.

```
    AFTER UPDATE ON table1.value  FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE database2.useragetable
    SET  age = NEW.value

    WHERE no = NEW.no
    END;
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Trigger to update table in another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910617/using-trigger-to-update-table-in-another-database)

Comment: @Nishita Thank you for giving me new insight.
however, where should I put the trigger. ? should I create another PHP script.. ? 
If I'm not asking to much, could you please put a screenshot of where the code should be put.. ?  ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following wiki to create a trigger:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/Trigger

1. In phpMyAdmin, select the database **(database1-table1)** that you want to work with.
2. Go to the SQL tab at the top of the page.
3. In the "Run SQL query/queries on database" form, change the Delimiter to $$. (Located in a small box at the bottom of the form)
4. Enter your SQL trigger into the main dialog box on the form.

Comment: Hi Nishita., I am still not sure if the link you gave me work in my case.
I tried to implement the answer from @fahim Parkar, but it said that "unrecognized statement type (near after) " I am not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: Please post the entire code of the trigger you are trying to run.

Comment: I have just put it in my question..
thank you very much for your help Nishita. ^^

Comment: do you have any way to solve the problem..  ? I would appreciate it.